# prevent URL category segment

Tags: url, categories

I have this tag:

```
{exp:channel:categories show="2" style="linear" channel="foto" show_empty="no"}
     <a href="{path='fotografie/studio'}">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

This results in the url: `domain.com/fotografie/studio/C2`
I don't want `C2` to show up in the url how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with "Global Channel Preferences" (admin > channel admin > global preferences) having "Use Category URL Titles In Links?" set to no.  When you set it to yes, the default behaviour will be to insert your category url indicator (which you control in the same spot), followed by the category url title (as in /category/category_url_title).

At least, that would be the typical default behaviour of the channel categories tag pair. You can certain override that a number of ways, both within the channel categories loop and the channel entries loop.

Comment: I have "Use Category URL Titles In Links?" disabled. But the category_segment still shows up.

Comment: It's because you are using the path variable - the default behaviour when used inside the channel categories loop is to add C#.  If you were to instead use simply /fotographie/studio then nothing would automatically be added to the URL. You'd just have to craft the linking behaviour to suit your needs.

Comment: Is "studio" a dynamic segment, a template, or a category?

Comment: studio is a template

Comment: So if you're planning to then using categories to filter within that template, you'd need to either set use "Use Category URL Titles In Links?" to yes and continue using the path variable (which would result in your url structure being fotographie/studio/category/whatever_your_category_url_title_is) OR you could eliminate the path variable and instead build it as path='fotographie/studio/{category_url_title}' but you'd wind up needing a bit of dynamic stuff happening in your entries loop to have it filter properly.

Comment: Hmm. Okay thank you for your hints. I guess I have to rethink this tag. Maybe put the a tag outside the categories tag.

Comment: Are you using EE categories for filtering at all?

Comment: Put another way, do you understand how EE uses a set URL pattern to dynamically filter entries by categories?  I've a categories primer posted on train-ee.com if it helps: http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/working-with-categories/

Comment: Yeah, I should have thought to point to that, Mike. Thanks! Kaspar, the link Mike has provided is an excellent starting point to use your URL as a dynamic filter on your entries.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll read trough your link. I Struggle with categories all the time. The case here however was not filtering, but giving the client the option to change {category_name} by himself. But since I have a bug where member-groups can't have access to category-editing, the whole operation is totally useless.